# How to easily make a ground plane in Altium 19.1

Tags: pcb, ground, altium

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make a ground plane in Altium 19.1? I have seen some guides but they appear to be in an older version of altium. I am also very new to PCB design and I know next to nothing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming what you want is a Polygon Pour (ground plane around the signals/ components)...

The procedure is the following:

Go into the "Polygon Manager"

[image]

[image]

When you are in this dialog box you can then make "New Polygon from"

And I usually like to create it from the board outline, which will create a polygon pour over all remaining space on the selected layer.

Comment: Awesome thanks heaps!

Comment: Polygon pours are definitely the recommended way to make planes nowadays. However, if you wanted to create an actual "Plane" (in Altium terminology), you have to go to the board layer stackup editor (shortcut D-K) and add it there.